# Apache2 on starts then immediately fails on debian9

Tags: apache

when starting Apache2 on my debian 9 (stretch) it starts then immediately fails.
there is nothing in the error log.
the syslog says this.

```
Aug  4 11:56:31 debian systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian apachectl[2414]: httpd (no pid file) not running
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  4 11:56:38 debian systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Any have any ideas on how I can trace exactly what is causing my server to shut down.

I have done a conf test and all confs are fine.

Comment: You're getting a `SIGSEGV` which means something is very broken somewhere.  Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall Apache?  Do you have many installed Apache modules?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the result the command below? Maybe if it fail show something more.

```
# service apache2 status
```

Well, if you see the port number, you can check any possible conflicts.

Try the command:

```
# lsof -i :"port_number"
```

"port_number" must be the port your apache service are using. This command will listing the programs that are use it. If there is another than apache2, you find the problem. Stop the other one service or program and restart apache2.

If the port that apache2 is free, and the error continue, show the content of status of apache2 service.